# Assign multiple values to keys of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I have to add multiple key-value pairs to an object.

I have an object called `hello`.

I know I have to do this to add key-value pairs to `hello`:

```
hello['a'] = 1;
hello['b'] = 2;
hello['c'] = 3;
```

The result will be `hello = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}`

I know we can do this to declare variables:

let [a,b,c] = [1,2,3];

In this case `a=1, b=2, c=3`

Is there an easy way like declaring variables to add key-value pairs to the object?

I know this is an error:

`hello['a', 'b', 'c'] = [1,2,3]`

Is there a one-line way to add key-value pairs to an object?

Comment: like `Object.assign(hello, {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3});`?

Comment: `hello['a'] = 1;hello['b'] = 2;hello['c'] = 3;` is one line

Comment: @Thomas, this works, can you add this as an answer, I can select it

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
hello = {
  ...hello,
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
}
```

Note that this would create a new object reference on `hello`

Answer (score 0):

You could use destructing assignment for object

```js
const hello = {}
hello["a"] = 1
hello["b"] = 2
hello["c"] = 3

const { a, b, c } = hello

console.log(a, b, c)
```

Or use destructing assignment for array, provided that you use `Object.values` to get the array of values from that object

```js
const hello = {}
hello["a"] = 1
hello["b"] = 2
hello["c"] = 3

const [a, b, c] = Object.values(hello)

console.log(a, b, c)
```

Comment: You've just specified the opposite of what the question asked for.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery (because you added the jQuery tag), this will do:

```
$.extend(hello, {a:1, b:2, c:3})
```